# Google Maps API returns "Invalid Request" in a valid request

Tags: php, google-maps, google-api, reverse-geocoding

i am trying to reverse geocode a bunch of addresses for my database. I have about 200 addresses, and half of them worked like a charm.. i did put the google maps request in a loop and it worked. There were about 100 adresses that returned a "INVALID REQUEST" message. I echoed the request url and put it in my browser and it returned a "Status: OK" and all the data. Why does my script return a invalid request and another browser-tab returns OK?

Thats the function i used:

```
function getLatLon($strasse, $plz) {
    $inhalt = simplexml_load_file('http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/geocode/xml?address='.$strasse.',+'.$plz.'&sensor=true');

    $geo['lat'] = $inhalt->result->geometry->location->lat;
    $geo['lon'] = $inhalt->result->geometry->location->lng;

    return $geo;
}
```

The request url in clear looks like this:
http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/geocode/xml?address=Dreik%C3%B6nigstra%C3%9Fe+12,+Erlangen&sensor=true

Would be awesome if someone could help me or detect an error :)
Regards, 
Philipp

Comment: check that $strasse and $plz are valid input for those that don't work (try comparing them to those that do), this is most likely the problem if it works some of the time.

Comment: hi, yes i thought that too but even with eliminating alle the spaces and special chars theres no change :(

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I am pretty sure the error is caused by the german characters you are sending unencoded. When you do it by browser the URL will be encoded automatically, but not automatically by your PHP-script.

Use [**rawurlencode**](https://www.php.net/rawurlencode) for this :

```php
$inhalt = simplexml_load_file('http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/geocode/xml?'.
                              'address='.rawurlencode($strasse).',+'.
                              rawurlencode($plz).'&sensor=true');
```

Comment: hi by the time you wrote this i got it working but you are right. i was sending unencoded strings and php could not replace any special characters. after putting everything on utf-8 it worked. Thanks!